# Check ssl certificate used by Android socket connection

Tags: android, ssl, keystore, sslsocketfactory

I'm inspecting an Android code that establish a ssl connection. The function createSSLSocketFactory is problem. It load a keystore. I don't know that the ssl connection is used for trust server certificate or send client certificate.

Please help me to check and give me some explanation.

Here the code:

```
private DefaultHttpClient createHttpClient() {
        DefaultHttpClient ret = new DefaultHttpClient(){
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient#createClientConnectionManager()
             */
            @Override
            protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                try {
                    URI uri;
                    uri = new URI(getURI());
                    if (Http.SCHEME_HTTP.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
                        registry.register(new Scheme(Http.SCHEME_HTTP, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                    } else if (Http.SCHEME_HTTPS.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
                        registry.register(new Scheme(Http.SCHEME_HTTPS, createSSLSocketFactory(), 443));
                    }
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    LogUtils.e(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
            }
            private SSLSocketFactory createSSLSocketFactory() {

                final Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
                final InputStream in = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.ippaps);

                ApplicationManeger apm = ApplicationManeger.getInstance();
                final char[] passwdchars = apm.getProperty(
                        PropertiesConstants.SSL_PASSWORD).toCharArray();

                SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = null;
                try {
                    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
                    try {
                        keyStore.load(in, passwdchars);
                    } finally {
                        in.close();
                    }
                    socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
                    socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LogUtils.d(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return socketFactory;
            }
        };

        return ret;
    }
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the [android javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#SSLSocketFactory%28java.security.KeyStore%29) is not very clear, when the `SSLSocketFactory` is created with a single `KeyStore` type parameter, this keystore is used as a trust store. It means that the keystore will be used to authenticate the server certificate but the connection will fail if the server requires a client authentication.